# Javascript RegEx to replace single underscores with a string of underscores

Tags: javascript, html, regex, textarea

I have a textarea where the user is able to type underscores. I want to convert the underscores that they type to a string of 10 underscores. I want this to be done in real time as they type.

_ => ***_*___**

I had thought that I could do something as simple as:

onkeyup:
textarea.value.replace(/_*/g, "***_*___**");

My thought being that it would match any string of underscores and automatically convert them to 10 underscores.

I get really odd behavior though. Typing an underscore results in 20 underscores. Also, it seems to be matching the left and right of any character I type. For example, if I type "A", I get:

___*A****_*__**

Does anybody know how to get this working properly? Seems so simple yet I am stumped. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the underscores I typed above got shortened. Any string of underscores > 1 character are meant to be 10 characters long in the above post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/_+/` rather than `/_*/`. `*` in a regexp matches zero-or-more of the character, so it's matching the empty string after the underscore and replacing it with 10 underscores. `+` matches one-or-more.

Answer (score 0):

change your pattern to /_{1,}/ this will match _ or *_* , your prior pattern matched _ and any number of characters afterwards.

Comment: err, I miss read the question, you want to change _ to _x10 but why would you want to do that :)  The pattern you want is /_{1}/ this will match one found and replace it with your _________ etc  with the /g modifier you will get each match and replace it.

Comment: My goal is to have the user type in a fill in the blank sentence. Instead of relying on them to type a bunch of underscores for the blank, I figure it would be easier to auto expand the underscore character. It would also ensure that all blanks are equal in length.